# "Semi-simplicity" of Lie algebra elements.

Tags: lie-algebras

Why are diagonalizable elements of Lie algebra called "semi-simple"?

Is there a notion of "simple" elements? Is it related to "semi-simplicity" of the Lie algebra?

Comment: I don't know much about lie algebras but there is a general concept of simplicity and semi-simplicity for modules and algebras over modules (a lie algebra is an algebra over a field with additional properties). Check the chapter VI of the book Algèbres et Modules (I. Assem) for further information..

Comment: The first question has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283229/what-is-the-relationship-between-semisimple-lie-algebras-and-semisimple-elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, this terminology is used as an analogy of what happens with matrices, and is related to the notion of *semi-simple module* mentioned in the comments.

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over the complex numbers.  Then $A$ defines a structure of $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module over $\mathbb{C}^n$, by letting $X$ act by $A$.  Now, this module is *semi-simple* (that is, it is a direct sum of *simple* (or *irreducible*) modules) if and only if the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.  Indeed, $A$ is conjugate to a Jordan normal form, and each Jordan block defines an indecomposable direct summand of the module.  It is not hard to see that a Jordan block defines a simple module if and only if it is one-dimensional.  Hence the module is semi-simple if and only if all Jordan blocks have size 1, which means that $A$ is diagonalizable.

For abstract Lie algebras, an element is then semi-simple if its adjoint action is given by a diagonalizable matrix.